# panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference in Krakend

Tags: krakend

I'm trying to run krakend run -c config.json, but it returns this[image]

here is my config.json:

```
"version": 3,
"name": "DigitalDocs API Gateway",
"port": 8000,
"timeout": "15000ms",
"cache_ttl": "300s",
"extra_config": {
    "github_com/devopsfaith/krakend-gologging": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "prefix": "[KRAKEND]",
        "syslog": false,
        "stdout": true
    },
    "github_com/devopsfaith/krakend-metrics": {
        "collection_time": "60s",
        "proxy_disabled": false,
        "router_disabled": false,
        "backend_disabled": false,
        "endpoint_disabled": false,
        "listen_address": ":8090"
    },
    "github_com/devopsfaith/bloomfilter": {
        "N": 10000000,
        "P": 0.0000001,
        "HashName": "optimal",
        "TTL": 1500,
        "port": 1234,
        "TokenKeys": ["jti"]
    }
}
```

My KrakenD version - 2.0.0

Please, help me to solve it

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution, please refer to the migrating documentation on : https://github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-config-migrator

You need to download the executable and execute it : ./krakend-config-migrator /path_to_krakend.json_directory

Since version 3, for example it's not anymore : "github_com/devopsfaith/krakend-metrics" but "telemetry/metrics"